# Removing item form JSON in powershell

Tags: powershell

I got a question to ask for removing an object in Json in powershell. I am fetching my results from powershell and i compressed it and placed into a JSON as shown below

```
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
$id = $vm.Config.InstanceUuid
$vmname = $vm.Config.Name
$geturl = "https://$nsxmanager/api/v1/fabric/virtual-machines?external_id=$id&included_fields=tags"
$getrequest = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $geturl -Authentication Basic -Credential $nsxtcred -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -SkipCertificateCheck
$getresult = $getrequest.results | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-Host ($getresult)
}
```

This will get the results

```
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}, {"scope":"test","tag":"text"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}]}
```

I am trying to remove the element {"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}  from all these results.

im not sure how i can remove it and wanted to seek some advice here how can I do so ?

Comment: This is not a valid json-structure

Comment: why is this not a valid? im doing a for loop. just i didnt add in the for loop earlier

Comment: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: ah, ok, every line is a request

Comment: yes.  do u have any idea how to  resolve this? I been trying to loop my object  getrequest.results.PSObject.Properties but it doesnt seem  to work

Comment: '{"tags":[{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"}, {"scope":"test","tag":"text"}]}' -replace '{"scope":"allow_access","tag":"external"},* *', ''

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering out these results by converting your JSON results to a PSCustomObject, iterating through the Tags attribute in a nested Foreach loop, and building a new PSCustomObject that does not contain those results you would like to filter:

```
$getresult = $getresult | ConvertFrom-Json

$FilteredTagsArr = @()

Foreach($Tag in $GetResult.Tags){

    If($Tag.scope -eq 'allow_access' -and $Tag.tag -eq "external"){
        #Do Nothing
    }Else{
        $NewObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Tag = $tag.tag
            Scope = $tag.scope
        }

        $FilteredTagsArr += $NewObj
    }

}

$GetResult.Tags = $FilteredTagsArr

Return $GetResult | ConvertTo-Json
```